# Access a TextBox from another class in workspace

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to use a `textBox`, which is on my main form `Form1` from other class. In class `Form1` I can use:

```
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayText));

and then

    private void displayAccFields(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbAccRoll.AppendText(packParameters.getPackage(3) + "");
    }
```

and it works fine.

How can I access this `textbox` for displaying something from a different class?

Comment: Are you using winforms, WPF, or ASP.Net?

Comment: It sounds like Winforms (Form1...)

Comment: pass your entire form to the class. Class myClass = new MyClass(this);

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But all fields on Form are private. Is it all right to change them to public?

Comment: And another dumb problem. Now when I want to display something from external class  through    `this.Invoke(new EventHandler( DisplayFunctions.displayAccFields(this, packParameters) ))`;   it says that "The name of method is requared"   The method in external class is `public static void displayAccFields(Form1 mainForm, SerialCommunicationProtocol packParameters)
        {
            mainForm.tbAccRoll.Clear();}`

Answer (score 0):

For sending values between two forms, you may

1. Send the values in the constructor of the second form. You may create a paramterized constructor and send the values when you initialize the form.
2. You may take a reference in to your first form in the second form.

In second form,

```
public Form1 objForm1;
```

and in First Form,

```
Form2 objForm2=new Form2();
Form2.objForm1=this;
```

and then you can use Form2's objForm1 to refer to Form1's textbox.

Comment: My external class is not a Form. It just a class with some functionality